# Python script is randomly failing due to the CPU utilization at 99% and kernels kills my script

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, cpu

I have a python script that is getting killed by the kernel after reaching 99% CPU utilization. The python is performing SQL queries against a postgresql db and appending the results to a single JSON file. The issue occurs when I reach query 150 and the CPU utilization goes to 99+% and then the kernel kills the script. How can I improve my code so this doesn't happen? I would greatly appreciate your help!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)


import re
import sys
import json
import pprint
import time

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

outfilepath = "crtsh2" + ".json"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

# DELAY = 0


def connect_to_db():
    start = 0
    offset = 10
    flag = True
    while flag:
        filepath = 'forager.txt'
        with open(filepath) as fp, open(outfilepath) as outfile:
            unique_domains = ''
            try:
                conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.itersize = 10000
                for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                    print(domain_name)
                    domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                    cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_keySize(c.certificate), x509_publicKeyMD5(c.certificate), x509_publicKey(c.certificate), x509_rsaModulus(c.certificate), x509_serialNumber(c.certificate), x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate), x509_subjectName(c.certificate), x509_name(c.certificate), x509_name_print(c.certificate), x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_subjectKeyIdentifier(c.certificate), x509_extKeyUsages(c.certificate), x509_certPolicies(c.certificate), x509_canIssueCerts(c.certificate), x509_getPathLenConstraint(c.certificate), x509_altNames(c.certificate), x509_altNames_raw(c.certificate), x509_cRLDistributionPoints(c.certificate), x509_authorityInfoAccess(c.certificate), x509_print(c.certificate), x509_anyNamesWithNULs(c.certificate), x509_extensions(c.certificate), x509_tbscert_strip_ct_ext(c.certificate), x509_hasROCAFingerprint(c.certificate)
                    FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                    c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                    lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                # query db with start and offset
                    unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
                    if not unique_domains:
                        flag = False
                    else:
                        # do processing with your data

                        pprint.pprint(unique_domains)


                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                        offset += limit


            except Exception as error:
                print(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: What is the message in the kernel log?

Comment: Does utilization always go to 99% at exactly query 150? Have you tried limiting the number of queries around that number to see if anything new/interesting  happens?

Comment: @Gigaflop If I limit the number of results to a 1,000 then the utilization doesn't go to 99%. However, I want to return all the results so limit the results isn't an option.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your help. I can't find the error message in the kernel log. I'm loooking in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf ? Is this the right one? If not, where should I look?

Comment: @bedford Depends on your Linux distribution. Ask a system administrator. If you don't have a log entry, how do you know that the kernel killed the backend?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That is what someone else told me since the script is dying. Do you have any idea of how to fix my script so it works though?

Comment: Never believe anything but hard evidence. The procedure you should do now is called *debugging*. If you think that an SQL statement is at fault, isolate it and run it in `psql`. If it shows the same symptoms, look into the PostgreSQL log, examine execution plans etc.